# Print individual split strings

Tags: python, string, split

The following code takes a string such as abcd#1234, removes the '#' and splits it into abcd and 1234

```
import sys
import re

print("User ID: {0}").format(sys.argv[1])
print("User Type: {0}").format(sys.argv[2])

sub = re.sub('[#]', '', sys.argv[1])
split = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", sub, re.I)
print(split.groups())
```

The output from `print(split.groups())` is 
<'abcd', '1234'>
How can I take an individual section of the split such as abcd and just output that?

Comment: `print(split.groups()[0])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
split.group(1) # --> 'abcd'
split.group(2) # --> '1234'
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group

Answer (score 1):

Use index.

**Ex:**

```
s = "abcd#1234"
import re
sub = re.sub('[#]', '', s)
split = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", sub, re.I)
print(split.groups()[0])
print(split.groups()[1])
```

**Output:**

```
abcd
1234
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the values of each as shown below:

```
data = split.groups()
if len(data) == 2:
    name, id = data
    print(name, id)
```

Or you can use [`group([group1, ...])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use split directly and get just tell it to take the second element.

```
import sys
import re

string="abcd#1234"
string1=string.split("#")[1]  # tells it to take the second element of the split

print(string1) # Prints 1234
```